# Android Studio: Cannot resolve Symbol | Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

As you can see on the screenshot, almost every import is red and that in every class except those programmed by me.
[image]
I have already tried the following things to solve the problem:

1. Deleted the .idea folder
2. "Invalidate Caches" in Android Studio

However, this has not achieved anything. Are there any other suggestions for solutions?

Comment: The "Cannot resolve symbol" error could be mismatched text encoding.  What encoding is Android expecting and what encoding are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps.

1. File > Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import > Java
   Click on the two options under java
2. Delete all the imports
3. Wait for the imports to kick in

Optional.
4. If it doesn't kick in do invalidate catches and restart after deleting .gradle .idea

Comment: how can i delete the imports?

Comment: select and delete the auto-import will import all the files again ..

Comment: hmm that doesnt worked, the 4. step doesnt help too